# How do I resolve Stream Closed error?

Tags: java, lucene

My code below is for getting TF-IDF value but I get an error

```
Caught a class java.io.IOException with message: Stream Closed
```

This is my code. I have tried looking for solutions to resolve it but I could not find any.

```
static void indexDocs(IndexWriter writer, File file)
    throws IOException {
    // do not try to index files that cannot be read
    if (file.canRead()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            String[] files = file.list();
            // an IO error could occur
            if (files != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    indexDocs(writer, new File(file, files[i]));
                }
            }
        } 
        else {
            FileInputStream fis; 

            try {                      
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                return;
            }

            try {
                // make a new, empty document
                Document doc = new Document();

                //Field termV = new LongField("termVector", file.) ;
                Field pathField = new StringField("path", file.getPath(), Field.Store.YES);
                doc.add(pathField);
                Field modifiedField = new LongField("modified", file.lastModified(), Field.Store.NO);
                doc.add(modifiedField);
                Field titleField = new TextField("title", file.getName(), Field.Store.YES);
                doc.add(titleField);
                Field contentsField = new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
                doc.add(contentsField);

                contentsField.setBoost((float)0.5);
                titleField.setBoost((float)2.5);

                doc.add(new LongField("modified", file.lastModified(), Field.Store.NO));
                doc.add(new TextField("title", file.getName(), Field.Store.YES));
                doc.add(new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
               //String Field.setBoost(1.2F);

               //probable error in this line
               if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) {
                    // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
                    System.out.println("adding " + file);
                    writer.addDocument(doc);
                } 
                else {
                    // Existing index (an old copy of this document may have been indexed) so 
                    // we use updateDocument instead to replace the old one matching the exact 
                    // path, if present:
                    System.out.println("updating " + file);
                    writer.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.getPath()), doc);
                }
            } 

            //Initially I thought fis.close() caused the error.
            finally 
            {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and indicate which line the exception is being thrown on.

Comment: That's the exact error. I copied it only. It did not indicate any line.

Comment: If you are not getting stack traces, you must figure out why not.  Maybe some oddball configuration in your IDE, or some such?  You *absolutely* should have got a stack trace here.  I certainly did when I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the same stream (`fis`) twice.

```
Field contentsField = new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
doc.add(contentsField);

//...

doc.add(new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
```

Even without the exception, you don't really want to add these twice.  You're duplicating the content.  Same goes for your "title" and "modified" fields.  Only need to add them once.